# How to create a rewriterule with multiple query strings?

Tags: string, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a few URL's from an old forum I wish to redirect to the same content on another forum. Here is a (fictional) example of an old URL: http://www.oldforum.com/forum/index.php?topic=21.0;msg=100

It should redirect to: http://www.newforum.com/threads/topic.11

Old and new URL's do not have anything in common, so I will be writing manual rewrites for each. I tried a number of things, but I can't get it to work. Here's what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^topic=21.0;msg=100$
RewriteRule ^oldforum/index\.php$ http://www.newforum.com/threads/topic.11? [R=301,L]
```

I'm close, right?

Comment: I assume you have a lot of links that need redirecting. If so, I would opt to just replace the old index.php with a new one that does the redirecting (with `header("Location: http://newforum/thread/$topic")`) based on `$_GET['topic']` and `$_GET['msg']`.

Comment: Those rules don't work for you? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Gerben: I can't use $_GET because those values have changed since I moved to new forum software (I should have probably mentioned that). So I am not looking for a way to dynamically convert my old URL's to the new URL structure; what I am looking for is the correct syntax to do what I described above.

Comment: Jon Lin: I do not get any errors, it's just that the rewriterule does not do anything at all. (Other rules do work correctly, it's just the one I posted above that doesn't work.)

Comment: Please re-read my comment. I suggest replacing the index.php of the old forum. That way you can get to $_GET and e.g. use an associative array to match the url in the new forum (as the new forum uses different id's of course).

Comment: Gerben: I re-read your comment and it makes sense to me now. I think I will implement your solution, seems the easiest way :-) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if I'm wrong:

The user in his/her browser types:

http://www.oldforum.com/forum/index.php?topic=21.0;msg=100

and the URL, on the server side, is redirected to:

http://www.newforum.com/threads/topic.14

You have to look into your query string to be able to do a comparison.

You've got the only solution that comes in my mind here:

[Using rewritemap for query string](http://daryl.learnhouston.com/2008/11/17/using-rewritemap-for-query-string-voodoo/)

From there you'll be able to do your own "correspondance table" or sort of.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The input and output topic ID's don't match. I assume he moved from forum software A to forum software B so it's not as simple to just pass the old ID to the new forum.

Comment: So you have a correspondance table or sort of to do?

Comment: Adding rewritelog to my htaccess results in an internal server error. If this should be enabled elsewhere, I probably cannot do it since I am on shared hosting. And like DaFrenk said, topic ID's are not shared between the old and new URL's, hence me trying to do this manually for each URL.

Comment: "Shared hosting"... everything is said. Updated my answer. Hope this helps (and the `-1` is strange)

Comment: Thanks for the help Olivier, but I will go with Gerbens suggestion for now. Not sure how you got the -1 either btw (I didn't vote).